# JavaScript Multiple Dependant Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am new to JavaScript and I'm struggling with the following code that will be in a form for registration of multiple candidates.

It creates 2 dependant select boxes (country and area) for each candidate.

Clicking the button 'Add Candidate' once allows the dependant boxes to work fine but clicking the button again stops it working.  Accessing the selected values from the form when there is more than one candidate is also impossible as they will overwrite each other.

I have tried creating the select names as arrays using a count variable which I increment each time the `ff` function is called but I can't get it to work.

All help will be much appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>Select Populate Test</title>

<script>
var UnitedStates = new Array();
UnitedStates[0] = "Texas";
UnitedStates[1] = "California";
UnitedStates[2] = "Arizona";
UnitedStates[3] = "Nevada";
UnitedStates[4] = "Florida";

var UnitedKingdom = new Array();
UnitedKingdom[0] = "Surrey";
UnitedKingdom[1] = "Kent";
UnitedKingdom[2] = "Dorset";
UnitedKingdom[3] = "Hampshire";

function populateDropdown(arry)
{
    document.myForm.stateSelect.options.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
    {
        document.myForm.stateSelect.options[i] = new Option(arry[i], arry[i]);
    }
}

function updateDropdown(str)
{
    var stateArray
    var selectedCountry;
    var countryDropdown = document.myForm.countrySelect;

    for (var i = 0; i < countryDropdown.options.length; i++)
    {
        if (countryDropdown.options[i].selected)
        {
            selectedCountry = countryDropdown.options[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (selectedCountry == 1)
    {
        stateArray = UnitedStates;
        populateDropdown(stateArray);
    }

    if (selectedCountry == 2)
    {
            stateArray = UnitedKingdom;
        populateDropdown(stateArray);
    }
}

counter = 0;
function ff()
{
        counter++;
        var box = document.getElementById("details"+counter);

        var cselectBox = document.createElement("Select");
        cselectBox.name="countrySelect";
        cselectBox.onchange = function()
        {
            updateDropdown();
        }

        var option1 = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
        option1.text="United States";  
        option1.value=1;  
        cselectBox.options.add(option1);

        var option2 = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
        option2.text="United Kingdom";  
        option2.value=2;  
        cselectBox.options.add(option2);

        document.getElementById("details"+counter).innerHTML+="</p><p>"+counter+". Candidate Country";
        box.appendChild(cselectBox);

        var box2 = document.getElementById("detailsx"+counter);

        var ccselectBox = document.createElement("Select");
        ccselectBox.name="stateSelect";
        document.getElementById("detailsx"+counter).innerHTML+="</p><p>"+counter+". Candidate City";
        box2.appendChild(ccselectBox);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" >
<input type="button" value="Add Candidate" onClick="ff(); populateDropdown(UnitedStates);"">
<!--- Note: 6 Candidates will be the maximum. -->
<div id="details1"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx1"><b></b></div>
<div id="details2"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx2"><b></b></div>
<div id="details3"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx3"><b></b></div>
<div id="details4"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx4"><b></b></div>
<div id="details5"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx5"><b></b></div>
<div id="details6"><b></b></div>
<div id="detailsx6"><b></b></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here. We'll tackle the one you're dealing with first.

When you name multiple controls with the same name, like stateSelect, you'll get the first one each time you try to reference it. If you instead set the id to `'stateSelect' + counter`, you'll get a unique id, which you can then retrieve with `document.getElementById()`. So in the function to populate the dropdown would look like this:

```
function populateDropdown(arry)
{
    var stateSelect = document.getElementById('stateSelect'+counter);
    stateSelect.options.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
    {
        stateSelect.options[i] = new Option(arry[i], arry[i]);
    }
}
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2MEqq/) I used to verify those changes.

You'll also need to add an event to each country dropdown to repopulate the state dropdown when it changes, and the structure needs a little work for that. If you're not opposed to frameworks, knockout would make this incredibly simple to run.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2MEqq/6/) with everything working correctly and comments added at key changes

**Update: Added link to the fiddle(s)**

Comment: Thanks for this, however I still can't get it to work. If you could post your full code later on it would be a great help! For the moment I am just trying to get my head around using Javascript directly before I move on to using frameworks.

Comment: See the fiddle I attached to the answer. I'll let you know when I add the rest to the fiddle, or you can use it to test your code instead. It's the fastest way to test client side code.

Comment: Now I have a link to a fully working implementation. I had to change several things to get it working and I added comments accordingly. Let me know if you have anymore questions.